# How to set the max and min value for year in html

Tags: javascript, php

I need to verify the max and min value from a date before submit a form. I want to send dates between 01-01-2005 and 12-12-2020. How can I do ti in php. If it's not possible in php, can be in javascript (jquery)

```
<input type="date" name="datepost" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');"/>
```

Comment: If it's _before_ submit, it is not possible in PHP; it must be JavaScript.

Comment: You can also use `min` and `max` attributes, since you're using `<input type="date">`

Comment: You can specify `min` and `max` attributes, like `min="2005-01-01"` and `max="2020-12-12"`, but you should always validate it on a server-side level too.

Comment: I must avoid to submit a form out of the range

Comment: Hey Don't Panic, is it possible to set it with html5?

Comment: Yes, @DiChrist - like this `<input type="date" name="datepost" min="2005-01-01" max="2020-12-12" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');"/>`

Comment: Post the rest of your HTML if you want a javascript method.

Comment: put it like an answer please. This is the best solution for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I mentioned in the comments, all you really need to limit the range of inputs in a date-input element is the `min` and `max` attributes. No JavaScript needed!

```html
<input type="date" name="datepost" min="2005-01-01" max="2020-12-12" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>"/>
```

This will limit the date, allowing January 1st, 2005 to be the minimum date to be available for selection in the form, and December 12th, 2020 to be the maximum date available.

Although, the user can specify the date by simply typing in a date of their choice (instead of selecting one with their cursor from the selection-window), outside of those parameters, so you should validate this in PHP (on a server-side level) too, which you should do in any case for all user-inputs. You can also validate it in JavaScript, but *always* validate server-side. See the other answer for a way of validating it in PHP.

Comment: There is an error in your code. The php needs to be closed.

Comment: Good eye, @WikusduPlessis. I've fixed that :)

Answer (score 0):

This PHP method will check to see if the posted date is between the range defined.

Post to this page to validate.

```
$user_time = date('Y-m-d', $_POST['datepost']);
$min = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('01-01-2005'));
$max = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('12-12-2020')); 

if (($user_time > $min) && ($user_time < $max)) {
    //Between Dates
}
else { 
 //Not between
}
```

Comment: While it's good to verify things server-side, OP asked *from a date **before** submit a form* :-)

Comment: @Qirel True. However, that could probably be used in conjunction with a dash of JS and a splash of Ajax. Question is a bit broad though. edit (Epik: not my downvote here).

Comment: Yep, obviously there are a million ways to do this. This is simply the PHP method, that *can* be executed at any time. I will write a JS method if OP posts more details.